# How write JUnit classes to test some java classes which is running in tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, testing, junit, external

I am using eclipse and using a plugin to trigger JUnit test suite. Now I need to write JUnit test cases which uses highly coupled java classes which can only be run in Tomcat server. How to start so that I can run the JUnit classes to test some java classes which is running in tomcat??

Any help is highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: It's hard to write proper tests for highly coupled code. The correct answer is: Introduce indirections to decouple the code from the environment, then test that.

Luckily you write "JUnit-Tests", not "Unit-Tests", because what you're doing is to use JUnit for an *integration test* (as you're attempting to test several layers together).

Another possibility is to [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) the (tomcat-)dependencies. This will enable you to get along without introducing many indirections. Be careful though: If you have too much setup of MockObjects for just a little bit of test and a single assertion at the end, this might not teach you too much about the correctness of your code.